# How To: Change Image visibility on rdlc export

Tags: rdlc

I Have an Image in rdlc report.
in the report i set visibility to false
I want that when I **Export** to PDF or EXCEL
To set the Image visibility to true.

- How do I do This?
- Is The a way to Catch the Export Event ?
- I don`t want to create a custom 'export'.

**Thanks …**

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found out how to do it was by creating a custom 'export' function...which really is quite simple.

Step 1: Create a parameter in your report called "ShowImage". I used the data type of String, made the prompt hidden and set a default value of "False". That way, when the report first runs in your report viewer on your page, it is not hidden.

Step 2: Change the visibility property for your image to an expression that has the following:

```
=CBool(Parameters!ShowImage.Value)
```

Step 3: Hide the Export Controls on your report viewer. Here is my example:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1"  runat="server" ShowExportControls="false" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Report1.rdlc" >
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Step 4: Add a button to your page and code the custom export. You will need to be sure to set the parameter you created in step 1.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Create ReportViewer
    Dim viewer As New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer()
    Dim p(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter

    p(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("ShowImage", "True")

    viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report1.rdlc")
    viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(p)

    'Export to PDF
    Dim reportContent As Byte() = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)

    'Return PDF
    Me.Response.Clear()
    Me.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Me.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf")
    Me.Response.BinaryWrite(reportContent)
    Me.Response.End()

End Sub
```

That's it. May I ask, why didn't you want to create a custom export event?